# Where do stty commands go in bash dotfiles? .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, stty

I'm trying to ensure that the flow control, xon-xoff, Control-S Control-Q feature
is turned off in all of my terminals/shells/tmux (so that I can
reliably use Control-S for something else)
It should work in X, urxvt, tmux, on consoles, ssh, ... everywhere.

In which dotfile should the configuration go?  What should it be?
My best guess:

```
# check xon/xoff settings
# stty -a | egrep -o -- '-?\<(ix\w*|start|stop)'

if [ -t 0 ]; then # term test?
    # Turn off TTY "start" and "stop" commands in all interactive shells.
    # They default to C-q and C-s, Bash uses C-s to do a forward history search.
    stty start ''
    stty stop  ''
    stty -ixon # disable XON/XOFF flow control
    stty ixoff # enable sending (to app) of start/stop characters
    stty ixany # let any character restart output, not only start character
fi
```

The examples I've found on my machine use .bash_profile, but that
doesn't seem to catch my non-login shells.  On the other hand,
putting stty calls in .bashrc assumes there's a terminal,
should I just test for a terminal ( if [ -t o ] ) or check $PS1?

Perhaps there's a better way to configure my terminal than "stty"?
Perhaps I should make all bash instances login shells?

stty is one of those arcane mysteries that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Using <kbd>Control-S</kbd> and the like, makes sense only in an interactive shell. So, I would put it into `.bashrc`, and to be sure test if the shell is really [interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f).